# How to set an attribute of a base class in a constructor of a sub class c++

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class, base-class

I have the following constructor in a class `Student` that is a subclass of a base class `Person`:

```
namespace Uni
{
    Uni::Student::Student(string majorCourse, int enrollNumber , string name, int age, bool isStudying)
        : Uni::Person::Person(std::__1::string name, int age, bool isStudying), majorCourse_(majorCourse), enrollNumber_(enrollNumber)    
    {
        cout << "[Temp] Student Default Constructor" << endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

I would like to set the attributes `name_`, `age_` and `isStudying_` (which are attributes of the `Person` class) to the values of `name`, `age`, and `isStudying`, but I get an error on this statement:

`Uni::Person::Person(std::__1::string name, int age, bool isStudying)`

> type name is not allowed

How can I fix this?

Comment: On a side note, never use `std::__1::string` directly, that is an implementation detail of your compiler's standard library.  Just use `std::string` instead, and let the library map it to whatever implementation it needs.

Answer (score 2):

You should just be forwarding the arguments along to the base class, so lose the typenames

```
 Uni::Student::Student(string majorCourse, int enrollNumber , string name, int age, bool isStudying)
  : Uni::Person::Person(name, age, isStudying),
    majorCourse_(majorCourse),
    enrollNumber_(enrollNumber)
 { }
```